# Where to get a product key for trial?

Tags: licence

I want to try Sharepoint 2013 standard (not Foundation).

So I downloaded it and now it asks me `Enter your product key`:

[image]

Where can I receive this product key for trial?

I thought it was the `Register for evaluation` step at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/evalcenter/hh973397.aspx but after I click on the `GET STARTED NOW` button I am only taken to a download page, no product key anywhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key is in the same page under the GET STARTED NOW button -

"Installation requires the following product key: "`NQTMW-K63MQ-39G6H-B2CH9-FRDWJ`

Cheers

Comment: Eh, happens to all of us :) You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful that if you wan to test SharePoint **Standard** you'll need a purchased key as currently, Microsoft is only providing an **Enterprise** trial key (which is `NQTMW-K63MQ-39G6H-B2CH9-FRDWJ`) and no standard trial key. Happy testing !